# libmpc.so.2 not found while compiling with Gcc

Tags: android, gcc, compilation, include

I want to use the cross-compiled gcc from: http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=getting-started:installation:android.
I want to compile on the Android device and execute the resulting file on the Android Device, so I am compiling on ARM for ARM.
I read that this cross-compiled gcc should work.
I am invoking the compiler like this:

```
gcc_dir/bin/arm-elf-linux-androideabi-gcc -Lgcc_dir/lib -Igcc_dir/include test.c
```

but I am getting the Error:

```
WARNING: generic atexit() called from legacy shared library
soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libmpc.so.2" needed by "/package.appName/files/gcc/bin/../libexec
/gcc/arm-elf-linux-androideabi/4.6.0/cc1";  
caused by load_library(linker.cpp:745): 
library "libmpc.so.2" not foundCANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE
```

Since I am running it on Android I can not use "export" to export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
What I tried to fix this problem:
1. Add the Library Path with -Lgcc_dir/lib
2. Add the Library Path with -Wl,-rpath,gcc_dir/lib
3. Add LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the environment Variables when executing (Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, environment_variables, files_dir))

**EDIT: I have no root permission!**
**EDIT 2:** I have made an strace of the Call and gcc is searching in the wrong path for the file:

```
6535 stat64("/vendor/lib/libmpc.so.2", 0xbeffefd0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
6535 stat64("/system/lib/libmpc.so.2", 0xbeffefd0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
6535 stat64("/vendor/lib/libmpc.so.2", 0xbeffefd0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
6535 stat64("/system/lib/libmpc.so.2", 0xbeffefd0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Is there an other method to change the Lib Path ?

I have no idea why the Library is not found and how to fix it.
Any Help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have received email asking help.

I'm afraid but **you need to add /data/local/gcc/lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.**

If it doesn't fix the issue, please tell me so. I'll have to think of another possibility.

PS: Possibly you need bash